# Добавить windows в grub2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, dual-boot

Пришлось мне поставить после Windows Ubuntu 18.04. у меня пропала Windows из grub. Я с помощью "Восстановление загрузки" вернул граб в Корень /dev/sda. Дальше с помощью grub customize добавил винду. Выводит вот такую ошибку.

```
enuentry "Windows 8" { 
insmod part_gpt 
insmod chain set root='(hd0,gpt2)' 
chainloader /EFI/microsoft/BOOT/bootmgfw.efi 
}
```

Помогите создать правильную настройку. Windows располагается в /dev/sda2 (Диск C).

Comment: а os-prober не сработал? команды из шапки /etc/default/grub выполнял? ручная правка конфига grub2 сопряжена с некоторыми граблями...

Comment: @Fat-Zer можете подробно расписать что надо сделать? Я просто новичок в ubuntu. Буду благодарен

Comment: @Fat-Zer Попробовал вторую инструкцию от сюда, не помогло https://losst.ru/oshibka-grub-ne-vidit-windows-10

Comment: а где, собственно, ошибка, которую что-то там у вас «выводит»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Ах да, прошу прощения. `Error: File "/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ntfs.mod" is not found.
Error: no such device: 4CE2F22DE2F21AC2.
Error: invalid EFI file path.`

Comment: 1. модуль для ntfs вам точно не нужен. 2. «дистанционно по фотографии» вам вряд ли удастся помочь. достаточно подробные объяснения на русском [тут, например](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)). 3. *ms/windows* — это «одна сплошная проблема». чем быстрее от неё избавляешься, тем легче становится жизнь.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin может быть тогда в вк поможете?

Answer (score 2):

В большинстве случаев ручная правка конфига grub2 (`grub.cfg`) избыточна и контрпродуктивна — этот файл генерируется специальным скриптом. Также этот же скрипт запускается автомачиске, например при обновлении ядра. В числе прочего этот скрипт находит установленные ОС с помощью утилиты `os-prober`.

Конкретное имя и как запускать скрипт меняется от дистрибутива к дистрибутиву, но практически всегда разработчики оставляют подсказку в шапке файла `/etc/default/grub`, например на debian:

> # If you change this file, run '**update-grub**' afterwards to update
>   # /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
>   # For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
>   #   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

Таким образом, при запуске `update-grub` (от root'а само собой) должен сам найти все установленные ОС и win в том числе.

Comment: `Генерируется файл настройки grub …
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-36-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-36-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
Добавление записи в загрузочное меню для конфигурации с микропрограммой EFI
`

Comment: Про Винду ни слова

Comment: @МаксимХалин, гм... больше добавить я вряд ли что-то смогу... с win я давно не сталкивался, а EFI так и не довелось пощупать...